# Hex String to Int,Short and Long in Scala

Tags: scala

Just can't find a way to transform an Hex String to a number (Int, Long, Short) in Scala.

Is there something like `"A".toInt(base)`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the Java libs:

```
val number = Integer.parseInt("FFFF", 16)
> number: Int = 65535
```

Or if you are feeling sparky :-):

```
implicit def hex2int (hex: String): Int = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)

val number: Int = "CAFE" // <- behold the magic
number: Int = 51966
```

---

Also, if you aren't specifically trying to parse a String parameter into hex, note that Scala directly supports hexadecimal Integer literals.  In this case:

```
val x = 0xCAFE
> x: Int = 51966
```

Isn't Scala wonderful? :-)

Comment: Hahah, mind block! You are right. Anyway, with Integer scala 2.9 resolves the parseInt method but with Short and Long don't. Any ideas?

Comment: I think "Short" is resoling to Scala's Short.  This works: val x = java.lang.Short.parseShort("FF", 16) // x: Short = 255

Comment: Came here when googling for the opposite, converting int to str. For the record: That is `Integer.toString(number, base)` or `BigInt(number).toString(base)`, if you happen to have a bigint. (but doesn't work with bases above 36, very annoying)

Comment: How do you go to Long (since that's in the question Google takes you here)?

Comment: `java.lang.Long.parseLong("CAFE", 16)`

Answer (score 31):

7zark7 answer is correct, but I want to make some additions.
Implicit from `String` to `Int` can be dangerous. Instead you can use implicit conversion to wrapper and call parsing explicitly:

```
class HexString(val s: String) {
    def hex = Integer.parseInt(s, 16)
}
implicit def str2hex(str: String): HexString = new HexString(str)

val num: Int = "CAFE".hex
```

Comment: Indeed, that implicit conversion sounded error prone. But this way you have fexibility and clarity at the same time. Thanx

Comment: You could just do the same with an implicit class:

`implicit class StringToHexStringAugmenter(val s: String) {
    def hex(): Int  = Integer.parseInt(s, 16)
}`

Less code for the same thing

Answer (score 12):

What about a one-liner?

```
def hexToInt(s: String): Int = {
    s.toList.map("0123456789abcdef".indexOf(_)).reduceLeft(_ * 16 + _)
}

scala> hexToInt("cafe")
res0: Int = 51966
```

And to answer your second item:

> Is there something like "A".toInt(base)?

Yes, still as a one-liner:

```
def baseToInt(s: String, base: String): Int = {
    s.toList.map(base.indexOf(_)).reduceLeft(_ * base.length + _)
}

scala> baseToInt("1100", "01")
res1: Int = 12
```

Answer (score 7):

Anyone wanting to convert a UUID from hex to a decimal number can borrow from Benoit's answer and use BigDecimal for the job:

```
scala> "03cedf84011dd11e38ff0800200c9a66".toList.map(
 |   "0123456789abcdef".indexOf(_)).map(
 |     BigInt(_)).reduceLeft( _ * 16 + _)
res0: scala.math.BigInt = 5061830576017519706280227473241971302
```

Or more generally:

```
def hex2dec(hex: String): BigInt = {
  hex.toLowerCase().toList.map(
    "0123456789abcdef".indexOf(_)).map(
    BigInt(_)).reduceLeft( _ * 16 + _)
}

def uuid2dec(uuid: UUID): BigInt = {
  hex2dec(uuid.toString.replace("-",""))
}
```

Then:

```
scala> import java.util.UUID

scala> val id = UUID.fromString("3CEDF84-011D-D11E-38FF-D0800200C9A66")
id: java.util.UUID = 03cedf84-011d-d11e-38ff-0800200c9a66

scala> uuid2dec(id)
res2: BigInt = 5061830576017519706280227473241971302
```

One practical application for this is encoding the UUID in a barcode, where Code128 produces a shorter barcode for all digits than it does with alphanumeric strings. See notes about subtype "128A" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code128#Subtypes.

Answer (score 5):

For Long and Short, it is also possible to use the Java methods directly like

```
Long2long(java.lang.Long.valueOf(hexString, 16))
```

where `Long2long` can be even be omitted in some cases.