# Python equivalent of int() function in scala and spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Python has an int() using which we can convert a string to int with base. Here is an example:

```
int("443205090D01DFF9000000", 16) - Output: 82443166943838217193914368
```

In scala there is a function Integer.parseInt(), but that's not working as expected and throwing NumberFormatException:

```
Integer.parseInt("443205090D01DFF9000000", 16);
NumberFormatException: For input string: "443205090D01DFF9000000"
```

Can someone help me out with the python equivalent in scala. And does spark also has similar kind of function ?

Comment: For Scala see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605816/765091 (This specific answer covers the case where the result needs to be a "BigInt")

Comment: For Spark see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055485/spark-convert-hex-string-to-decimal

Comment: The REASON that fails is that the `Integer` type is only 32 bits, and that constant is 88 bits.  It won't even fit in a `Long`.  Python's infinitely long integers spoil us.